# Why is it not possible to use SJF (Shortest Job first) in Linux?

Tags: linux, scheduling, algorithms

why it is not possible to use SJF as the scheduling algorithm for Linux?

Comment: is there some context to this question, that is, some particular reason you're asking? Or some practical situation? Or are you just asking out of academic interest? Or for homework...? Do you have any ideas on why an SJF would be impossible/hard to use? How do you even know it's not possible?

Comment: Is this a theoretical question about algorithms, or a practical question about who decided what the Linux kernel should use, when, and why?

Comment: Its for academic interest, i know that starvation is one, If there is a steady supply of short process, the long process may never get the chance to be executed by the processor. But i am wondering what other reasons why SJF is not used for linux

Comment: If it's just for academic interest it's probably [off-topic here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask), "_You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face_"

Answer (score 2):

Off the top of my head, I could think a number of reasons why [Shortest Job First](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_job_next) is a complete no-go in any general-purpose system.

The first problem is right there in the name, you need to be able to determine the "shortest" job up front. An `ls` on a local directory is probably rather short, but the runtime of e.g. a shell process can anything from a fractional second (for a short script) to weeks or months (for my interactive shell). The OS can't know, and in many cases, the utility itself can't, either. Not to mention that you'd usually want many interactive utilities that are able to run simultaneously. (Also, as far as I understand SJF in the basic form, it's non-preemptive, with all the associated problems there.)

Of course, if you split up the concept of "jobs" to a smaller unit than a whole process, that might be a bit more useful. But that doesn't really fit with the concept of processes as they are, there's no way for a process to signal the start of a new "job". Even if there were, you'd still need to know how long the jobs are. You could trust on the process telling, but on a multi-user system that would cause some unfairness. Or you'd need to have some checks in place to make sure the advertised job length matches the real job length, but that's starting to sound like a real operating system scheduler now...

It's not that similar concepts haven't been used. As far as I recall, there have been features in the Linux schedulers that try to tell the difference between interactive processes (ones that are idle for a long time, but then do a short job that should have a high priority) and non-interactive ones (which do work on a steadier rate).

Comment: Processes are scheduled to use a CPU time-slice, but every system call (including I/O) interrupts that slice. Processes that fail to use their whole time-slice receive higher priority in the scheduling queue, so CPU-heavy processes get fewer full timeslices. So you might view that as SJF, but implemented on a timescale of milliseconds. Having a very small mix of dedicated jobs means that many resources are often idle. The only overhead of a job waiting for its timeslice is memory occupancy, and Moore's Law nailed that issue many years ago.